# How to make jq treat argument as numeric instead of string?

Tags: bash, jq

How to make `jq` treat an input argument as numeric instead of string? In the following example, `CURR_INDEX` is a Bash variable which has array index value that I want to extract.

```
jq --arg ARG1 $CURR_INDEX '.[$ARG1].patchSets' inputfile.json
```

I get the following error:

```
jq: error: Cannot index array with string
```

I tried the workaround of using `bash` `eval` but some `jq` filters do not work properly in `eval` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert it [to a number](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tonumber), like this:

```
jq --arg ARG1 1 '.[$ARG1|tonumber]' <<< '["foo". "bar"]'
"bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

`--arg` always binds the value as a string. You can use `--argjson` (introduced in version 1.5) to treat the argument as a json-encoded value instead.

```
jq --argjson ARG1 $CURR_INDEX '.[$ARG1].patchSets' inputfile.json
```

To see it in action, you can reproduce your original error:

```
$ jq --argjson ARG1 '"1"' '.[$ARG1]' <<< '["foo", "bar"]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "1"
```

then correct it:

```
$ jq --argjson ARG1 1 '.[$ARG1]' <<< '["foo", "bar"]'
"bar"
```